# Spring Boot Admin Server upgraded - Apps in Kubernetes Cluster no longer register

Tags: kubernetes, spring-boot-admin

We are running admin server under K8 and leverage K8 discovery.  When we upgraded to Spring 2.5.4, the admin server was no longer able to discover other applications in the cluster.   These applications were not upgraded.  The only upgrade was to admin server.

You'll see in applications.yml that I've tried to put some DEBUG log settings.  Maybe I need other DEBUG settings (any suggestions welcome)?  I'm not getting any errors or warnings.  I'm just getting stuff like this:

```
01/27/2022
11:31:18.596 AM -0500
2022-01-27 16:31:18.596 DEBUG 1 --- [     parallel-1] d.c.b.a.server.services.IntervalCheck    : check status for all instances
Host:
x.xxx.xxx.xx
Name:
xyz-admin-server.log
Category:
xyz/Applications/xyzadminserver/dev

152
01/27/2022
11:31:15.867 AM -0500
2022-01-27 16:31:15.867 DEBUG 1 --- [     parallel-1] d.c.b.a.server.services.IntervalCheck    : check status for all instances
Host:
x.xxx.xxx.xx
Name:
xyz-admin-server.log
Category:
xyz/Applications/xyzadminserver/dev

153
01/27/2022
11:31:08.836 AM -0500
2022-01-27 16:31:08.836 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] d.c.b.a.s.c.d.InstanceDiscoveryListener  : Discovering new instances from DiscoveryClient
Host:
x.xxx.xxx.xx
Name:
xyz-admin-server.log
Category:
xyz/Applications/xyzadminserver/dev

154
01/27/2022
11:31:05.000 AM -0500
2022-01-27 16:31:05.906 DEBUG 1 --- [     parallel-2] d.c.b.a.server.services.IntervalCheck    : check info for all instances
Host:
x.xxx.xxx.xx
Name:
xyz-admin-server.log
Category:
xyz/Applications/xyzadminserver/dev
```

Details of the application java, pom.xml, and application yamls are below.  They are the result of combing through Stackoverflow posts, tutorials, etc., trying lots of different things.

This upgraded admin server builds just fine, runs just fine, but nothing gets registered - the UI shows no instances.  Can someone see something I'm doing wrong?

AdminServerApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableScheduling
public class AdminServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-cloud</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

/src/main/resources/application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: xyz-admin-server
  cloud:
    discovery:
      enabled: false
    config:
      enabled: false
      discovery:
        enabled: false
    kubernetes:
      catalog-services-watch:
        enabled: true
        catalogServicesWatchDelay: 5000
      discovery:
        all-namespaces: true
        filter: "#root.metadata.name matches '.*'"
        service-labels:
          "[app.kubernetes.io/part-of]": ".*"
      enabled: true
      config:
        sources:
          - name: application
          - name: application-env
          - name: ${spring.application.name}
          - name: ${spring.application.name}-env
      reload:
        enabled: true
        period: 60s
        strategy: refresh
  boot:
    admin:
      notify:
        ms-teams:
          ignore-changes: ""
      context-path: /admin
      discovery:
        ignored-services: "debug-*"
        converter:
          management-context-path: /management
          health-endpoint-path: /health
  profiles:
    active: ${env},kube

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false

management:
  info:
    git:
      mode: full
  endpoints:
    loggers:
      enabled: true
    web:
      base-path: /management/
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    loggers:
      enabled: true
    health:
      show-details: always
    restart:
      enabled: true
  metrics:
    export:
      datadog:
        enabled: false

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes: DEBUG
    de.codecentric.boot.admin: DEBUG
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this ? I am facing the same issue.